# Group through joined tables Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I was hoping this would be simple, but in essence I would like to count the number of Users who have certain attributes through a join table in Rails 4.

I have a table called `Views` which holds three columns:

```
  t.references :viewer
  t.references :viewed
  t.boolean :sentmessage, default: false
```

I then have the fields references as:

```
belongs_to :viewer, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :viewed, :class_name => "User"
```

Each user record is then associated with a number of other records like Stats, Questions and a number of others. I'm interested in effectively counting how many `viewers` of a `viewed` record are Male or Female (and other search fields) which is data all held in User.stat.gender.name etc.

I'm trying to use a `group` statement but have no idea how to drill down and count the number of Males etc. I've tried:

```
@results = View.where(viewed: 63).group("viewer.stat.gender")
```

But this is so wrong it's frightening.

Any help to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out finally. For anyone else who is interested:

```
View.where(viewed_id: 63).joins(viewer: {stat: :gender}).group("name").count
```

Didn't realise what an INNER JOIN was but some research and some trial and error means I can now show information about the users who have visited.